# ascending descending table column with combobox in swt?

Tags: sorting, combobox, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am create eclipse RCP application and use SWT table and i am trying to ascending descending column value but not working in column shell value is not change so please help me.

my column value (cell value) is combo box , how to sort column combo value in my table.

Comment: Hi sir i am posted my code and pleas help me sir how to solve my problem   .

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    Random random = new Random();
    final int[][] data = new int[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i] = new int[] { i, random.nextInt() };
    }
    // create a virtual table to display data
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.VIRTUAL);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setItemCount(size);
    final TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column1.setText("Key");
    column1.setWidth(200);
    final TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column2.setText("Value");
    column2.setWidth(200); 
    table.addListener(SWT.SetData, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
          TableEditor fd_editor = new TableEditor(table);
            fd_editor.grabHorizontal = true;
             CCombo combo = new CCombo(table, SWT.CHECK);
             combo.add("ABC");
             combo.add("XYZ");
             combo.add("PQR");
             combo.add("BABA");
             combo.add("PAVAN");
             combo.add("RAJA");             
             combo.select(1);     
        TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
        int index = table.indexOf(item);
        int[] datum = data[index];
        item.setText(0, Integer.toString(datum[0]));
        fd_editor.setEditor(combo, item, 1);       
      }
    });
    // Add sort indicator and sort data when column selected
    Listener sortListener = new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        // determine new sort column and direction
        TableColumn sortColumn = table.getSortColumn();       
        TableColumn currentColumn = (TableColumn) e.widget;              
        int dir = table.getSortDirection();     
        if (sortColumn == currentColumn) {          
          dir = dir == SWT.UP ? SWT.DOWN : SWT.UP;
        } else {                          
          table.setSortColumn(currentColumn);
          dir = SWT.UP;
        }
        // sort the data based on column and direction
        final int index = currentColumn == column1 ? 0 : 1;
        final int direction = dir;
        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
            int[] a = (int[]) arg0;
            int[] b = (int[]) arg1;
            if (a[index] == b[index])
              return 0;
            if (direction == SWT.UP) {
              return a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return a[index] < b[index] ? 1 : -1;
          }
        });
        // update data displayed in table
        table.setSortDirection(dir);
        table.clearAll();
      }
    };
    column1.addListener(SWT.Selection, sortListener);
    column2.addListener(SWT.Selection, sortListener);
    table.setSortColumn(column1);
    table.setSortColumn(column2);
    table.setSortDirection(SWT.DOWN);
    shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x, 500);
    shell.open();    
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: This should be part of the question, and not an answer.